# Read & extract objects out of properties file with the following format in java/spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

My entity class

```
    public class User {

        String name;
        String userName;
        String password;
        String[] roles;

        static class ROLES {
            static String ADMIN="ADMINISTRATOR";
            static String USER="USER";
        }

        public User(){

        }

        public User(String name, String userName, String password, String... roles) {
            this.name = name;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
            this.roles = roles;
        }
    }
```

Format of the properties file

```
user[0].name=Sujal Mandal
user[0].userName=sujal12
user[0].password=sujal123
user[0].roles=ADMIN,USER,SUPER_USER
user[1].name=Busra Ercelik
user[1].userName=busra12
user[1].password=busra123
user[1].roles=USER
```

I would like to write an util class which will read the properties file & return me the objects of Users

**What would be the best way of doing this in Java/Spring boot enviornment?**

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: As a side note, avoid spaces in role names; it's asking for quoting issues later on. It's better to use constant-style naming with underscores.

Comment: chrylis advice taken, can you show me an example of this @ConfigurationProperties real quick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is shown below where in you need to use `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("myproject")
public class UsersPopulator {

 private List<User> users;//all users will be populated from application.properties

//add getter method

}
```

Your `application.properties` file looks like the below:

```
myproject.users[0].name=Sujal Mandal
myproject.users[0].userName=sujal12
myproject.users[0].password=sujal123
myproject.users[0].roles=ADMIN,USER,SUPER USER
myproject.users[1].name=Busra Ercelik
myproject.users[1].userName=busra12
myproject.users[1].password=busra123
myproject.users[1].roles=USER
```

You need to ensure that `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is added to the launcher class file.

Comment: the entity class needs to have an empty constructor , mine didn't have any & your answer is correct :) Thanks man

Comment: Also, just updated the last line, you need `@EnableConfigurationProperties`  as well on the SpringBoot launcher class

Comment: that isn't necessary but yeah helps to make the code more readable, thanks once again.